# PXE a W7x64 Task Sequence on a Lenovo X250 with SCCM 2012 SP1 & Windows ADK

Tags: windows-7, pxe-boot, sccm

My purpose is to PXE boot a Windows 7 (x64) Task Sequence on a Lenovo X250 with :

- SCCM 2012 SP1
- Boot Image 4.0 x64 / WinPE 6.2 generated with Windows 8 ADK

With [these](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/ht074984) Lenovo drivers for SCCM , I tried several configurations :

- WinPE Boot Image Driver Packs 3.1 x64 + Windows 7 x64 Pack Driver
- WinPE Boot Image Driver Packs 5 x64 + Windows 7 x64 Pack Driver.

Both of them didn't allow the download of WinPE and display the endless `"connecting to server........."` message.

Now, I would like to know the recipe of downloading Boot Image for a Lenovo X250 w/ SCCM 2012 SP1.

If anyone knows, Please share...

Comment: Is this already a working environment?

Comment: So this boot image is already used in a working environment? I need to know this so I can answer better

Comment: I checked the SMSPXE.log & It showed that my Image Boot had a DP update problem. 
I just resolved that problem & now, with the same configuration the problem evolved has following : 
WinPE 6.2 loop, after downloading.
When I prompt a command support & lauch an ipconfig, I got nothing else than a "Configuration IP" message displayed.
Despite the fact that I used the Lenovo's WinPE's Driver Pack 5.0 x64, the network card of my X250 seemed to be not recognized... 
Does somebody please, has a solution ?
Best Regards

Comment: What is the target WinPE version for that driver pack?

Comment: I deploying Lenovo X250 with SCCM 2012 SP1 so the boot image that I have generated are 4.0 / kernel 6.2. The drivers Packs are those : http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds102312

Comment: My configuration has been just improved as following :
 
- SCCM 2012 SP1
- Laptop Lenovo X250
 
- Boot Image 4.0 / Kernel 6.2
- Driver from the Lenovo DriverPack WinPE 5.0 for the storage
- Driver I218 W8 x64 for the network
 
- Based W7 x64 SCCM TS
- W7 x64 SCCM Lenovo Driver Pack X250
Now I get a TCP IP configuration but after accessed the Test Support, my WinPE doesn't download the Task Sequence & the X250 reboot.
Any additional advice please ?